# Flutter JSON String/Int commands

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm trying to make an app that retrieves **data** from [**this JSON list**](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/) and **parse** this data to a `listview`.

With my **code** below, the first record I expect to see is `ID`, `NAME` and `PRICE`, but it appears that I can't retrieve the `PRICE`, because it's an `int` and I'm calling for a `string` from the **JSON** list.

Also, 'PRICE' is an int just like 'ID', as sam mentioned below, but 'ID' is fetched just fine whereas 'PRICE' just says 'NULL' in the list view

I don't know how to fix this, and hope I can get the answer I'm looking for on this platform.

FirstPage.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: StarWarsData(),
  ));
}

class StarWarsData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  StarWarsState createState() => StarWarsState();
}

class StarWarsState extends State<StarWarsData> {
  final String url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/";
  List data;

  Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    setState(() {
      var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      data = resBody["data"];
    });

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Cryp-Tick Crypto Exchange"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Id: "),
                            Text('${data[index]["id"]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black87)),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Name: "),
                            Text('${data[index]["name"]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.red)),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Price: "),
                            Text('${data[index]["price"]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black87)),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getSWData();
  }
}
```

The error I receive in the **Debug Console**:

```
E/flutter (25480): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (25480): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' where
E/flutter (25480):   _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
E/flutter (25480):   String is from dart:core
E/flutter (25480):   List is from dart:core
```

Comment: stop using **Bold** every where , for best quality don't use **help me** or **i hope help me** or something like that , notice every one know **stackoverflow** is for helping . for more information read here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, sorry sam I'll remember this for next time, any ideas with this problem though?

Comment: if the problem is about `price` type you must get same error for `ID` because ID is int too. that's right ?

Comment: Oh yeah true, the thing is ID is parsed correctly but price just spits out 'null' so it must be something else

Comment: read this document in `flutter` web site . it was a example for parsing in this document : https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/background-parsing/

Comment: Will do, thanks for the documentation

Comment: Hey Sam, do you know how to change this **Text('${data[index]["max_supply"]}',** to find a value with a decimal, because this only returns an int. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the problem is what you think. You have your data typed as a `List`:

```
List data;
```

And you're populating it like this:

```
data = resBody["data"];
```

The error says:

> type `'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>'` is not a subtype of type `'List'`

This suggests that resBody["data"]` is a map and not a list, and if you look at the JSON in the URL you're pulling, it starts like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
```

That `data` object is not a list/array, it's a an object/map. You should change the type of your `data` variable to `Map<String, dynamic>` of convert the data to a `List` before storing it in the variable.

---

**Edit after some comments**

I was able to make this work by adding `.values.toList()` and stripping the JSON down to just the first two records:

[image: Flutter]

However with all of the JSON from that url it seems to error. So, maybe something in the JSON is triggering a bug. Even more strangely, it seems to work fine in DartPad!

Comment: Looks like a great response, I’ll let you know how it goes tomorrow as it’s a little too late in my country.

Comment: Im quite new to the language, could you provide an example of how I would implement this into my code?

Comment: Maybe try changing it to `data = resBody["data"].values;`, since that shout give you a list of the values you want?

Comment: Okay so now in the debug console, I'm getting this error: 
E/flutter (10989): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List' has no instance getter 'values'.
E/flutter (10989): Receiver: Instance(length:100) of '_GrowableList'

Comment: @JakeBailey Turns out you may need .toList too... However, I still hit issues with the full json, but not with a smaller set - see my edit. I think you may have found a bug. I think something in the JSON might be crashing the json decoding.